# Does air gap between enclosed chamber and manometer influence the manometer reading?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, pressure, water, air

We have an enclosed chamber filled with water. From the top of the chamber there is a metallic tube connecting the chamber to a monometer. We increase the pressure of the water inside the chamber  buy pushing down with a plunger. There is airgap between the monometer and the water. Can the monometer show the pressure inside the chamber accurately? Or to what degree will the air compressibility influence the reading of the manometer?

[image]

Comment: The air in the tube up to the manometer will be compressed just as much as the air in the headspace above the water.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you for your reply. That is correct and clear.